# Markarth Guards seem to be broken and I can't get out of the hold to let the place reset

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It all started with me accidentally shouting at a guard. I'm only level 4, so it didn't even make a crack in his health bar. But now, no matter what I do, they just kill me. I've mostly just been trying to leave the town with healing but they're just as fast as I am and they destroy me.

I'm an imperial, but my voice of the emperor doesn't seem to be working. Granted, I'm not exactly sure how to use it.

Also, fast travel won't work because I'm surrounded by enemies.

I tried reverting to a previous save but the safest one I have is way back at Alvor and Sigrid's house when I was level 1 and still had to retrieve the Dragonstone.

Killing all the guards is out of the question, as well. Lydia's already dead to them so I'm on my own and definitely not strong enough to kill them all.

How do I get out of this??

EDIT: I was able to figure out how to use my Voice of the Emperor. My bounty wasn't too high and it's all good, now. :)

Comment: What platform are you using? On PC you could use the `coc` command

Comment: Drop a level or two in the difficulty setting.

Comment: @KallumTanton I'm on XBox360 unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried yielding? When you have your sword drawn in a fight, just sheath it and most enemies will stop combat. If a guard accepts your yield, they will talk to you about paying your bounty or going to jail.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider [Yielding](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Yield) (emphasis mine):

> Yielding is a way of ending a fight started by accident. If your opponent shows a high disposition toward your character, you can ask him to stop fighting by holding the block key and activating the NPC, as if you wanted to talk to him. (**In Skyrim, this was changed to just sheathing your weapon and seeing if the person will accept it.**)

Yielding will usually work on NPCs, but not against monsters (so you should be able to yield to the Markarth guards).

After you yield, you can choose to pay the fine for whatever crime you've committed, go to jail (from which you can often escape), or continue to resist arrest.

Your [Voice of the Emperor](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Voice_of_the_Emperor) power should work as well:

> Voice of the Emperor is a Greater Power possessed by all Imperials, which allows them once a day to cast a powerful Pacify effect on all NPC targets within a 75 ft radius.

Note that its radius is limited to 75 feet, so try to have as many of the guards as close to you as possible before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, by constantly attempting a yield (lowering your weapon in combat with guards) eventually they should agree and let you live. If the guards behaviour doesn't change because you died, try saving before you enter combat and simply reload the save over and over until they accept. Make sure to damage a guard if they don't accept the yield, this "reload method" seems to work on shopkeepers just fine, maybe it works similarly on guards. What I suggest you do is you sheath your weapon near the guards, if they accept yield you either pay off the bounty or choose to go to jail, and if they reject you pull your weapon back out, strike at them and reload the save until they accept the yield. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old but just in case it helps someone else....

When confronted by a markarth guard, I accidentally chose to option to fight/escape - once the guards attacked, they absolutely would not accept my yield, no matter how many times I died and respawned. I then got stuck on a save point that when I respawned, I would die almost instantly because there were about 10 guards that would all hit me at the same time  my solution was to shout as soon as I spawned, ran for my life out of the city walls until the guards stopped chasing me, waited until nightfall, and then returned to the city. They confronted me on sight but this time, they again asked if I wanted to go to jail/pay up/fight.

I think because of the quest involving the guards, they are extra hostile and less likely to yield. However, in play it ends up being a bit janky, unfortunately!

Answer (score -1):

As the option of Yielding was already suggested, am gonna say try drinking some fair amount of Healing and stamina potion. Not only it restores the health and stamina, opening up the inventory option will allow you to assess the situation and plan your escape. This came in handy for me to evade many fights when my character level was low.

Not a great method to resolve your problem. But it might work if you do it right.